# How do I know that jQuery validation rule is imposed on a particular element or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to update jquery validation for different scenarios. I have tried `$("#elementId").rules("remove", "ruleName")` for a few elements, but it is giving an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` for elements which don't have validation rules.

Comment: That error usually means that you're trying to use a rule that does not exist or you've not properly included the plugin.  We can't really help if you don't show us any code.

Comment: If this field has no validation rules, then what are you trying to remove?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to update jquery validation on for different scenarios.

What scenarios?

> I have tried `$("#elementId").rules("remove", "ruleName")` for a few elements, but it is giving an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` for elements **which don't have validation rules**.

`.rules("remove")` is only used to remove validation rules that have already been assigned to a particular field.  It seems pretty pointless to "remove" something from a field that is not being validated.  If this field has no validation rules, then what are you removing?  Regardless, what you describe would not give the error message, or any other JavaScript errors.

See:  [jsfiddle.net/m5vys55g/](http://jsfiddle.net/m5vys55g/)

> How do I know that jQuery validation rule is imposed on a particular element or not

As you can see in my demo above, I am attaching `.rules("remove")` to a field that has no rules and no JavaScript errors are generated, so you wouldn't normally need to know in advance which elements have validation rules... just use `.rules()` in either case.